# Changing a value of a variable which is inside an if statement that referencing a flag

Tags: go, mux, gorilla

I have the following Go program, which is a static file server. I'm getting the following error in the console:

```
..\static\main.go:45:5: cannot use handlers.CombinedLoggingHandler(os.Stdout, r) (type http.Handler) as type *mux.Router in assignment: need type assertion
..\static\main.go:52:5: cannot use handlers.CompressHandler(l) (type http.Handler) as type *mux.Router in assignment: need type assertion
```

How can I use flags with the Gorilla Mux router and `CombinedLoggingHandler` or `CompressHandler`?

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"

    controllers "<this_is_a_local_repo>"
    common "<this_is_a_local_repo>"
)

var (
    host     = flag.String("host", "127.0.0.1", "TCP host to listen to")
    port     = flag.String("port", "8081", "TCP port to listen to")
    logging  = flag.Bool("logging", false, "Whether to enable HTTP response logging")
    compress = flag.Bool("compress", true, "Whether to enable transparent response compression")
    dir      = flag.String("dir", common.Abs("public"), "Directory to serve static files from")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()

    r := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    r.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(*dir))))
    r.PathPrefix("/").HandlerFunc(controllers.IndexHandler(*dir + "/index.html")) // catch-all route for 404

    l := r
    if *logging {
        l = handlers.CombinedLoggingHandler(os.Stdout, r)
    }

    h := l
    if *compress {
        h = handlers.CompressHandler(l) // gzip all responses
    }

    srv := &http.Server{
        Handler: h,
        Addr:    fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s", *host, *port),
        ReadTimeout:  5 * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
        IdleTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
    }
    log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
}
```

Comment: `var h http.Handler = r`, if ... then `h = handlers.CombinedLoggingHandler(os.Stdout, h)`, if ... then `h = handlers.CompressHandler(h)`. No need to do `l := r` and `h := l`, doing `h = middleware(h)` should be fine.

Comment: you are assigning a *router to `CombinedLoggingHandler` and `CompressHandler`. They both require handler type which is not the case here

Comment: @Himanshu you mean *return* right? Because so far as they take an `http.Handler` as an argument the code is ok, since `*mux.Router` implements that interface. The problem is that they also *return* an `http.Handler` but the type of the value on the left hand side of the assignment is `*mux.Router` and not `http.Handler`... The problem is in what type those two functions *return*, not in what they require as an argument.

Comment: Based on the first comment his should fix it https://play.golang.org/p/zD5Ran7t3Kj

Comment: @mkopriva `http.Handler` is a function using `servemux` as receiver. You have declared a variable of that type. Hanlder is a type ? I have never seen declaring a variable of function type. Please elaborate. I am in learning phase

Comment: @Himanshu [http.Handler](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) is not a function.

Comment: But If we are implementing an interface type we should implement its function too. I hadn't see it. So how things works. Please can you explain.

Comment: @Himanshu `r` is of type `*mux.Router`, this type already implements the `http.Handler` interface. And so `var h http.Handler = r` declares a variable `h` of type `http.Handler` and assigns it the value of `r` which is correct and will compile because `r` (*mux.Router) has the `ServeHTTP` method, which is required to implement the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to add middleware to your gorilla/mux router.

You can add middleware with [`Router.Use()`](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Router.Use).

`Router.Use()` takes a [`mux.MiddlewareFunc`](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#MiddlewareFunc), which is simply a function with the signature `func (http.Handler) http.Handler`. Most middleware you will run across matches this signature or can be easily wrapped to do so, as in the example below.

Ripped off from some of my own internal code:

```
func myLoggingHandler(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return handlers.CombinedLoggingHandler(os.Stdout, next)
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    if logging {
        r.Use(myLoggingHandler)
    }
    if compress {
        r.Use(handlers.CompressHandler)
    }

    http.Handle("/", r)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("[::]:8009", nil))

}
```

Comment: I accepting this as an answer, because it gives even simpler solution to my problem, but I think mkopriva's solution is more universal (for fasthttp). I also noticed that `flag.Bool` accepting every console argument as true, even `false`, because of missing type casting. So I use `flag.String` and `if logging == "true" {}`.

Comment: My bad, boolean flags's format should be `-foo=bar`, sorry. https://golang.org/pkg/flag/